# How can I get a value from an array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

i get info from my Api in ASP.netCore
in angular i have this :

```
0: {Id: 3, Role_Name: 'ITAdmin'}
1: {Id: 4, Role_Name: 'Admin'}
2: {Id: 5, Role_Name: 'user'}
```

and want to get the value out of that array for my CurrenUser
somthing like this in array or something else

```
var rolename  = itdamin , admin , user


 var id = 3, 4, 5
```

for show the rolename and RoleId Separated

thanks for helping me :)

Comment: "somthing like this in array or something else"???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you can found an edit code which print 2 arrays

```js
let id = []
let role = []
const input = [{
    Id: 3,
    Role_Name: 'ITAdmin'
}, {
    Id: 4,
    Role_Name: 'Admin'
}, {
    Id: 5,
    Role_Name: 'user'
}, ];

for (let index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
    id[index] = input[index].Id;
    role[index] = input[index].Role_Name
}
console.log(id)
console.log(role)
```

Comment: can u write a code that get me the value in string Array

Comment: Yes, of course! I edited

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce` to handle your array and get ids and rules you wish:

```js
// sourse array
const tmp = [{
    Id: 3,
    Role_Name: 'ITAdmin'
  }, {
    Id: 4,
    Role_Name: 'Admin'
  }, {
    Id: 5,
    Role_Name: 'user'
  },
];

// default empty target object
const defaultList = {
  ids: [],
  roles: [],
};

// handler of your sourse array
const reducedObj = tmp.reduce((obj, item) => {
  // getting id and role from array item
  const {Id, Role_Name} = item;
  
  // update list
  return {
    ids: [...obj.ids, Id],
    roles: [...obj.roles, Role_Name]
  };
}, defaultList);

// getting ids and roles from reduced object
const {ids, roles} = reducedObj;

console.log('ids: ', ids);
console.log('roles: ', roles);
```

Simpler way:

```js
// sourse array
const tmp = [{
    Id: 3,
    Role_Name: 'ITAdmin'
  }, {
    Id: 4,
    Role_Name: 'Admin'
  }, {
    Id: 5,
    Role_Name: 'user'
  },
];

// default empty target arrays
const ids = [];
const roles = [];

// handler of your sourse array
tmp.map(item => {
  // getting id and role from array item
  const {Id, Role_Name} = item;
  
  // update lists
  ids.push(Id);
  roles.push(Role_Name);
});

console.log('ids: ', ids);
console.log('roles: ', roles);
```

Comment: why not `ids = tmp.map(x=>x.Id)` and `roles = tmp.map(x=>x.Role_Name)`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna could be like an option. Why not. I've added this example just to expand example to make it a bit readable.

Comment: Usually it's preferable in JavaScript, that is lent to functionality and immutability is seen as a value :)